# How to switch workspace diractory in Github actions on Windows runner

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to fix a problem with CodeQL, which fails due to lack of disk space. I noticed that there's a nice tasty 80GB available on C: drive, while the D: drive offers only 10GB of free space. The simplest way would be to just change workspace root to C:\a\ directory. Unfortunately the `env` setting doesn't change the working dir, I tried to debug it with following file:

```
name: "CodeQL"

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "codeql-analysis-debug" ]

jobs:
  analyze:
    name: Analyze
    runs-on: windows-latest
    permissions:
      actions: read
      contents: read
      security-events: write
    env:
      GITHUB_WORKSPACE: C:\a\

    steps:
    - run: |
        echo ${{ github.workspace }}
        echo $env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE
```

But the result is still the same:

```
Run echo D:\a\project-name\project-name
  echo D:\a\project-name\project-name
  echo $env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    $env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE: C:\a\
D:\a\project-name\project-name
D:\a\project-name\project-name
```

I also tried to set `jobs/analyze/defaults/run/working-directory` to `C:\a\`, but it was ignored too. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to use env and defaults settings. The result is still D:\a\. I expected C:\a\